# Firebase Database listen only specific childrens

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a chat application using firebase database but I'm having some problems.
[image]

This is my database. I want to add a listener to Messages but just for the values for `User->UID->chats->Chat IDs`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it twice: first get the chat id list based on user id, then get the messages data for each of those chat ids.

```
// consider you have you user (FirebaseUser) object ready
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + user.uid + "/chats")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages/"+snapshot.getKey())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
                        ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot messageSnapshot) {
                            // I changed the snapshot name to make it easier to read
                            // here messageSnapshot.getKey() is message ID
                            // and messageSnapshot.getValue() will contain data you need (I think)
                        }
                        ...
                    );
            }
        }
        ...
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to access

```
 final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Messages").child(read);
```

Comment: I gave this example based on your screenshot, it could be `database.getReference("Messages").child();` so you could display all the messages in your database

Comment: But won't it get the messages of all rooms? I thought it's not a good way to do that since if I send a message, every user will get that message.